# how to cache data on multiple server by reading form database only once?

Tags: database, caching, client-server

I am working on e-commerce application and it is having **25GB** of data in **database**, I am loading all the data into 5 servers at the start of the application and caching the same(mostly on hashmap) because there will be `15K` request per minute and I can't hit database that many times. It takes around 1 hour to load the entire database on one server. Now I need to do the same on other servers also. Is there any way we can replicate the same from the first server instead of reading from Database?

Answer (score 0):

Replicating 25GB of cached data around seems like it may not be the best approach...

I would suggest looking further up the call hierarchy and maybe re-architecture some of the design.  Look into potentially implementing key-value storage systems (NoSQL), look at caching the frequently used data and not *all* data. Maybe look at replicated databases as well since if your caching this much data you could probably just improve the throughput to your data stores and have them handle the job for you.